# Decode a JSON tuple to Elm tuple

Tags: json, elm

My JSON looks like the following

```
{ "resp":
    [ [1, "things"]
    , [2, "more things"]
    , [3, "even more things"]
    ]
}
```

the problem is that I can't parse the JSON tuples into Elm tuples:

```
decodeThings : Decoder (List (Int, String))
decodeThings = field "resp" <| list <| map2 (,) int string
```

It compiles, but when ran, it throws

```
BadPayload "Expecting an Int at _.resp[2] but instead got [3, \"even more things\"]
```

For some reason it reads `[3, "even more things"]` as only one thing and not as tuple in JSON format.
How can I parse my JSON into a `List (Int, String)`?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match your description - `[1, "things" ]` is a JSON *array* and not a JSON *object* (which I'd expect since you mentioned JSON tuples). Try `{1, "things" }` instead, or change your Elm decoder to accept a list of lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a decoder which turns a javascript array of size two into an Elm tuple of size two. Here is an example decoder:

```elm
arrayAsTuple2 : Decoder a -> Decoder b -> Decoder (a, b)
arrayAsTuple2 a b =
    index 0 a
        |> andThen (\aVal -> index 1 b
        |> andThen (\bVal -> Json.Decode.succeed (aVal, bVal)))
```

You can then amend your original example as follows:

```elm
decodeThings : Decoder (List (Int, String))
decodeThings = field "resp" <| list <| arrayAsTuple2 int string
```

(Note that my example decoder does not fail if there are more than two elements, but it should get you pointed in the right direction)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Why isn't there any default implementation for tuples, when they're represented as lists?

Comment: There used to be `tupleN` decoders that were implemented in native javascript, but those were [removed](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/3b999526e08ac517c0223a55c78cb13e752be3f8) and the recommended handling is to use [index](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/c341774223da6ad30eb67d1628cbea68c6fcd27e). I'm not sure what the reasoning was exactly.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is more complicated than it needs to be. Try:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode

decodeTuple : Decode.Decoder (Int, String)
decodeTuple = 
    Decode.map2 Tuple.pair 
        (Decode.index 0 Decode.int) 
        (Decode.index 1 Decode.string)
```

and then, as you note, for the list

```
Decode.list decodeTuple
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not get either Chad Gilbert's or Simon H's solution to work with Elm 0.19. I am quite new to Elm, but this is what I could get to work:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode
import Json.Decode.Extra as Decode

{-| Decodes two fields into a tuple.
-}
decodeAsTuple2 : String -> Decode.Decoder a -> String -> Decode.Decoder b -> Decode.Decoder (a, b)
decodeAsTuple2 fieldA decoderA fieldB decoderB =
    let
        result : a -> b -> (a, b)
        result valueA valueB =
            (valueA, valueB)
    in
        Decode.succeed result
            |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field fieldA decoderA)
            |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field fieldB decoderB)
```

Comment: Hi @Rene, I've been asked to review your question because you're new. The only thing I'd say is that maybe providing a link to Chad or Simon's solution and some context to your problem would help people to get you an answer quicker. Hope that helps. ;)

Comment: Ok. Chad's solution is the accepted one, and Simon's is also above in this thread. My post is the solution that I could get to work - so it is more of a alternative to Chad's accepted solution, then a question. My problem was the same as the original poster.

Comment: Sorry, dude. That's shit UI on SO's part. When it said review the post, it showed me your post as if it was the question, not an answer! I thought the people and the problem you were referencing were well known in the Elm community and that you'd extended from that! Honestly, what ridiculousness! Ignore my comment above. smdh!

Comment: you are declaring an object into a tuple. the question used arrays of two elements

Comment: My code assumes the json data is `[val1, val2]`, whereas as your data seems to have been `{field1: val1, field2: val2}`