# Decode a tuple in elm

Tags: elm

I'm looking for a way to decode a tuple with two elements in elm.

[[String, Bool]]

The outer list is easy enough to parse with Json.list, but how do I decode the array as a tuple ? I tried the solution from [Decode a JSON tuple to Elm tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703764/decode-a-json-tuple-to-elm-tuple) but all I get is errors about types of Decoder and Maybe, I assume something changed in elm since that answer. Or maybe I'm missing an import, I don't know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simplest is

```
map2 (,) (index 0 string) (index 1 string)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of elm 0.19 use:

`map2 (Tuple.pair) (index 0 string) (index 1 string)`

https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#changes

Comment: Thanks, link is dead though: [https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#functions-changed](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/docs/upgrade-instructions/0.19.0.md#functions-changed)

Comment: Thanks @Lennart! The link is up to date now

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to generically convert an array to a tuple.

This is because an array can be of arbitrary length, while a tuple is of a pre-determined length; determined at compile-time.

So to perform the conversion you need to add some constraints, which of course will depend on your problem domain. For example, I may decide that only arrays with two elements can be converted. Like this:

```
import Array exposing (Array)

arrayToTuple : Array a -> Maybe (a, a)
arrayToTuple array =
    case Array.toList array of
        (a::b::_) -> Just (a, b)
        _ -> Nothing
```

Due to the differences in length, the function must return a `Maybe (a, a)`; or a similar type which captures the two possible scenarios.

The subtle issue is this: **the conversion is *lossy* and you'll have to account for this at some point.**

For example, you can reject ill-suited arrays in the decoder, but then you'll have to account for failed decoding. Or, you can *capture* the failure in a `Maybe`, and get sucked into `Maybe`-land. Either way, you'll have to account for the potential of a failed conversion.

Comment: I'm not really worried for the length, as this array is just a Haskell tuple encoded with Aeson, it won't ever be a different length (or if it does, it's because I changed it on purpose). In any case I'm fine with the Decoding just failing in the unlikely case it would happen